# Count the number of dates in a column that are greater than the current date in Google Sheets/Excel

Tags: date, excel-formula, compare, google-sheets-formula

I want to have a cell that checks a specific column for dates that are greater than today but for some reason it isnt counting.

Here is what I have:

`=COUNTIF('ORDER DATE'!H3:H990;"<TODAY()")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`=COUNTIF('ORDER DATE'!H3:H990; ">" & TODAY())`

Also notice that for **greater than today** you should use another operator: `>`.